# How to initialize struct to safe values

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have a function which needs to initialize a struct to a known safe state. the following code what i have done so far, i dont think this correct or maybe, however how do i correctly intialize the struct to safe values, as it needs to passed around the rest of my code;

```
Boolean sysON(FooSystem * sys) {
    List * list = malloc(sizeof(list));

    sys->cash[0].denom = 1;
    sys->cash[1].denom = 1;
    sys->cash[2].denom = 1;
    sys->cash[3].denom = 1;
    sys->cash[4].denom = 1;
    ...

    sys->list = list;
    sys->stockFileName = "bar.dat";

    return FALSE;
}
```

the struct is;

```
typedef struct Foo_system {
    Coin cash[8];
    List * list;
    const char * coinFileName;
} FooSystem;
```

or instead should i be malloc(sizeof(foo)) all of the variables in the sysON function?

**EDIT**

when i have more than 4 of the following pices of code it crashs my program;

```
  sys->cash[0].denom = 1;
  ...
  sys->cash[4].denom = 1;
```

my program crashs and i recieve the following error - 
*** Error in `./vm': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000d0c030 ***
 Found out what my problem was, as persons said below i wasnt allocating enough memory.

Comment: "Correct values" is a concept defined by *you*. So we can't tell you if it's correct. You did do the right thing by initializing it after allocating it, however.

Comment: You need to show how you call the function and how the `sys` variable is declared, or nobody will be able to answer the question. Also it isn't clear what "safe values" means, that's something on the application level.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `list` is a variable of type `List *`. For a pointer to `List` type, the required memory is of the size of type `List`, not a pointer-to-`List`.

So, the problem is

```
    malloc(sizeof(list));
```

allocates way less memory than expected. You need

```
    malloc(sizeof *list); // same as malloc(sizeof(List));
```